# grep -v *string* and grep -v string creating wildly different results

Tags: terminal, grep, command-line-interface

```
grep -v mystring myfile.txt
```

returns ~300KB

```
grep -v *mystring* myfile.txt
```

returns ~7GB

....what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is wrong. By default `grep` takes regular expressions as argument along with the command line flags. The one you have attempted `*mystring*` is a shell glob expression which expands to a possible set of filenames containing the string `mystring`. So your `grep` commands becomes the following; on an assumption that you have filenames containing `mystring`

```
grep -v mystring1 foomystring2 foomystring3 myfile.txt
```

which could produce unexpected results depending on the contents of those files.  The right way would be to use the greedy match quantifier `.*`

```
grep -v '.*mystring1.*' myfile.txt
```